# Sending data to mysql using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am newbie to web programming. I would like to insert data into MySQL DB, for that I am using PHP and this data is coming from a form in a Bootstrap Modal. When I click the `Save`button, nothing is happening. I been following a [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZDj_0gRTgs) and I have done exactly that tutor is doing. What went wrong with my code?

**HTML Code and JavaScript:**

```
 <body>
<p><br/></p>
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addData">Insert data</button>

   <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="addData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="addlLabel">Insert Data</h4>
            </div>
            <form>
            <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nm">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nm" placeholder="Name here">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="em">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="em" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hp">Hone Number</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="hp" placeholder="Your Phone">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="al">Address</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="al" placeholder="Your address"></textarea>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" onclick="saveData()"class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function saveData(){
    var name=$('#nm').val();
    var email=$('#em').val();
    var phone=$('#hp').val();
    var address=$('#al').val();

    $.aja({
       type:"post",
       url:"server.php?p=add",
       data:"nm="+name+"&em="+email+"&hp="+phone+"&al="+address,
       success: function(msg){
        alert('Success Insert data');
       }
    });

  }
</script>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ajax','root','');
$page=isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'';

if($page=='add'){
 $name=$_POST['nm'];
 $email=$_POST['em'];
 $phone=$_POST['hp'];
 $address=$_POST['al'];
 $stmt=$db->prepare("insert into users values('',?,?,?,?)");
 $stmt->bindParam(1,$name);
 $stmt->bindParam(2,$email);
 $stmt->bindParam(3,$phone);
 $stmt->bindParam(4,$address);

 if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Success";
 }else{
    echo "Fail".mysqli_error();
 }
}else if($page=='edit'){

}if($page=='del'){

}else{

 }
?>
```

I have used the development in Chrome, no error is being shown.

Comment: print_r($_GET); and print_r($_POST); please share......

Comment: Not `$.aja({` it must be `$.ajax({`.

Comment: let me resolve that

Comment: @Naincy I tried ` print_r($_POST);` it showed nothing that's why I realised the  data was not being sent...but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Giovanrich send data in object`{}` format.below in answer.

Comment: @Hekmat Okay, let me do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo error.You have `$.ajx({})`.It must be `$.ajax({})`.Also send your data in object format.like this..

```
 $.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url:"server.php?p=add",
       data:{nm:name,em:email,hp:phone,al:address},
       success: function(msg){
        alert('Success Insert data');
       }
    });
```

Comment: Why does the dev tools not complain or show it? Thanks that was the error. It is now working, will accept your answer

Comment: See error on `console` tab.Sure there must be an error.

Comment: I agree it must show and error but when I put`ajx` console shows nothing other than a a blue `>`